# Is there a way to update the map without affecting the URL?

Tags: google-maps

I created a destination map and need to delete one business. However, I have used the URL as a code to a QR point.

Will deleting the one business change the URL on the map and affect the advertising on the QR code?

Please follow the link for more info and a better understanding.

https://www.alliedartscouncil.com/parklandarttour

Thank you and hope to hear back.

Comment: I don't see an obvious map on [the page you link to](https://www.alliedartscouncil.com/parklandarttour), where would it be? What is it's URL? Why would changing the map on that page change the pages URL?  Please provide _all_ the information required to answer your question **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 1):

The link pointed to by the QR code:

[image: QR code from link]

Is a [Google MyMap](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1fI5VbsvxcH6C-R4jKfpmcB2W_buaCPPc&hl=en&ll=53.55967291969056,-114.44730475&z=9):

```
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1fI5VbsvxcH6C-R4jKfpmcB2W_buaCPPc&hl=en&ll=53.55967291969056,-114.44730475&z=9
```

[image: screenshot of Google MyMap]

The URL doesn't change if you edit the map to add or remove places (unless you make a completely new map, then you will get a new URL/id for the map).  It will change if you need to recenter the map or change its zoom level, as those are encoded in the URL.